# How to add props function in jquery by using react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm hoping you encounter the same issue of mine. I have react code that need a jquery event like (click, change). here is my code.

```
export default class SamplePreviewComponent extends React.Component<Props, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderChoiceButton();
  }

  renderChoiceButton() {
    $("input.st").on("click", function() {
      let value = $(this).val();
      this.props.addDependentSample(value);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { sampleTree } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="row pl-1 pr-1 pt-0 mb-1">
        <div className="columns bg-black20 pt-1 pb-1 border-radius-sm">
          <div className="mb-1">
            <p className="subheader">
              <strong>
                <small>SAMPLE #1</small>
              </strong>
            </p>
            {sampleTree.root.label.trim().length > 0 && <h4>{sampleTree.root.label}</h4>}
            {sampleTree.root.subLabel &&
              sampleTree.root.subLabel.trim().length > 0 && (
                <span className="subheader">
                  <small>
                    <strong>{sampleTree.root.subLabel}</strong>
                  </small>
                </span>
              )}
          </div>
          <div>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sampleTree.root.generatedHtml }}
              className="red"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

if you check my return value of my component. there is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` added. The output is like this

```html
<div>
  <div class="fancy-checkbox fancy-hover small mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="st" id="_0" name="17[]" value="1">
    <label for="_0">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="fancy-checkbox fancy-hover small mb-0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="qt" id="_1" name="17[]" value="2">
    <label for="_1">2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user click the checkbox. I'm going to add and event using a jquery

```js
renderChoiceButton() {
  $("input.st").on("click", function() {
    let value = $(this).val();
    this.props.addDependentSample(value);
  });
}
```

I get an error  `Cannot read property 'addDependentSample' of undefined`. Maybe, because it comes from the react props and the jquery cannot read it. How can I add event using jquery that will connect the function to react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can resolve this error - a simple approach would be to store a reference to your component instance (ie `componentInstance` as shown below), and then access the component's props through that instance, like so:

```
renderChoiceButton() {

    // Store reference to component for access in click handler
    const componentInstance = this;

    $('input.st').on('click', function() {

       let value = $(this).val();
       // Access props for the component via componentInstance
       componentInstance.props.addDependentSample(value);
    });
}
```